# Как получить свойства объекта?

Tags: php

есть такой объект

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#163 (14) { 
["@attributes"]=> array(3) { 
   ["available"]=> string(4) "true" 
   ["group_id"]=> string(9) "718708141" 
   ["id"]=> string(8) "31479124" } 
["url"]=> string(59) "http://bole-ro.com.ua/p31479124-plate-zhenskoe-dlinnoe.html" 
["price"]=> string(3) "380" 
["currencyId"]=> string(3) "UAH"
["categoryId"]=> string(7) "3421923" 
["picture"]=> array(8) { [0]=> string(61) "https://images.ua.prom.st/127308492_w640_h640_8w1s5dpa6ky.jpg" }
```

как можно получить свойство `available` свойства `@attributes`. учитывая что объект храниться в переменой `offer` пробовал так `offer->@attributes->available` получил ошибку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть метод [attributes()](http://php.net/manual/ru/simplexmlelement.attributes.php), его и надо использовать, чтобы достать атрибуты.

Пример:

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<a>
 <foo name="one" game="lonely">1</foo>
</a>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
foreach($xml->foo[0]->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
}
?>
```

Результат выполнения данного примера:

```
name="one"
game="lonely"
```

Вам надо, соответственно, писать так:

```
offer->attributes()
```

и скорее всего достать значение можно будет так:

```
offer->attributes()->available
```